# Filtering out text content on some criteria, e.g. about myself

Tags: algorithm

What is the specialist area where if I have a set of blog posts for example, and I would like to filter out the ones which may be about myself or irrelevant by some criteria? I know I could have a list of words to look for (which would be a lot of it is's about myself or anything/one else - the combinations won't end), to do my filtering by, but this is no scalable strategy. The levenschtein algorithm would also come in handy but I think this is an entire research area?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful:

[The Anatomy Of A Search Engine](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html)